# Ajax don't show me the selected data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title>Scroll Pagination</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:{
                'offset':0,
                'limit':5
            },
            succes:function(data)
            {
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        });
    });



    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {
                    'offset':0,
                    'limit':3

                },
                succes:function(data)
                {
                    $('body').append(data);
                }
            });
        }

    });


</script>


<style type="text/css">
.blog-post{border-bottom: solid 4px black; }
.blog-post h1{font-size:40px;}
.blog-post p{font-size:30px;}
</style>


</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the html and ajax code.
And here is the PHP code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'table') or die();
print_r($_GET['limit']);

    if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $limit=$_GET['limit'];
        $offset=$_GET['offset'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8");
        $data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM portf LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");


        while ($portf = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                echo '<div class="blog-post"><h1>'.$portf['title'].'</h1><p>'.$portf['category'].'</p></div>';
            ?> 
<?php }}else{echo "fail";} ?>
```

I have no idea why in the index I can't see nothing what can I do to solve this problem? I saw this example on youtube and is working but..when I'm trying to do the same nothing appears.

Edit: 
[Statuts in network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6P3I.png)

Comment: Hard to guess. You checked your Network tab on the Developer Tools of your browser(F12)  ? There you can see if there is any error in the request as well in your php script.

Comment: any errors in your console? also at the end of your while loop, why close php and then open it immediately again?

Comment: No errors in console or something.. :(.. about php close..my bad....I have no idea why is no working

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown In Network tab is ok, it looks good..

Comment: I mean, the response of the request is ok ? Is there your html or the *"fail"* message ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown the status code is 200 OK

Comment: Sure but what about the response ? If there is any php error in your script, it will be there even in a successful request.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The response is good, I have all data I need..no error in PHP script..just a second I will come with a screenshot

Comment: Did you noticed that your ajax callback is `succes` in your code ? It's that a typo in your question ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown it's a good question hmm..I have no idea about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in your code at time of ajax call due to which it does not enter in success.

Change

```
 succes:function(data)
```

To

```
 success:function(data)
```

It should be "success".